# Cannot run Java with Webdriver due to “all_links_webpage cannot be resolved” error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am unable to run a Java program using Web driver due to an "Unresolved compilation problem: all_links_webpage cannot be resolved". Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
package lightart_TC;
import java.util.List;

public class light {
    private static int linkscount;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        int size,List;
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        List <WebElement> linksize = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        linkscount = linksize.size();
        System.out.println("no. of links");
        Links = new string[linkscount];
        System.out.println("list of links available");
        for (int i = 0; i < linkscount; i++)
        {
        links[i]= linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println(all_links_webpage.get(i).getattribute("href"));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < linkscount; i++) 
        {
        driver.navigate().to(links[i]);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
```

}}

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
all_links_webpage cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `w` in `WebElement` is small in your code.

Use this:

```
List<WebElement> linksize
```

import package:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```

The code below works fine for me:

```
public class light {
    private static int linkscount;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        int size,List;
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.changning.sh.cn/jact/front/front_mailpublist.action?sysid=9");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List <WebElement> linksize = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        linkscount = linksize.size();
        System.out.println("no. of links");
    }
}
```

Comment: After done the above changes I'm getting unresolved compilation problem error in the line.... public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {

Comment: Please EDIT your post and update it to show the current information, including the ENTIRE error message. For runtime errors include the entire stack trace (even if it's long).

Comment: Above is the Updated one.....still I'm getting the same error

Comment: I have added a code which work fine for me.

Comment: clean your project before running it .. In eclipse goto to project --> clean -> ok